# Render Django multi-steps forms

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, multi-step

**I want to create a multi-steps (model)form: my objective is to have it split in 4 pages, each with a save/update function and the possibility to entierly skip a page (when i have only optional fields).**

I created a models.py with 4 classes(and relative urls, views, etc..) and tried to use createview, listview and even formsets for grouped-forms (to keep pk for the entire 4 pages session), but I can't render it.

**What is the best way to render it?**

Thanks in advance!

**PS.** *I do not wish to use Django-tools-wizard module if possible, having already crispy-forms and other modules, as I don't know for certain it will be compatible with the already working ones.*